# Magento - How to add extra button like "Add to cart" and Redirect to external url from grid view, list view and product page view.

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I want to add extra button like "Add to cart" for example "Live Demo". Then, as their are no of products each one have unique demo link that I will add from "Manage attributes" section of admin.  I want to redirect "Live Demo" button to that particular product page demo url and after their should be also a button at header section for "Buy now".

Currently I have added a extra button in product page.
How can I do this on grid view and list view.

[image]

By making changes in /var/www/magentodemo/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $Demo ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $Demo ?></span></span></button>
```

But which class name and onclick function I should call for this button to redirect to external url (to call external url attribute.)

Anyone have done this before. please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of of you need to make your new attribute used in

> product listing under manage attributes

and after that you can make use of this new attribute in grid pages in list.phtml file of your current theme by calling that new attribute as other you can see in your file like name  etc.

thanks and let me know if you have any issues

Comment: I have created an attribute also able to get that attribute value on product page, grid view and list view. but just need to apply on that button?  Where I can make changes in above button code?

Comment: you will need to chnage this  onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)
to     onclick="window.location = <?php echo $Demo ?>;"

thanks

Comment: what should I write their ? Can you please explain in brief. My attribute name is demourl .

Comment: have you check the other code in the file that how the nane of the product is displaying there. And you have to use the code of your attribute not a label in the file to get the value of your attribute. 
you can use this if your attribute code is demourl <?php echo $_product->getDemourl() ;?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102878/discussion-between-rahul-dambare-and-rohit-goel).